# How to rename a field name in a XFA pdf file?

Tags: pdf, xfa

I need to generate (via pdf mail merge) IRS forms with data.
Most everything works except for the fact that, for some reason, IRS has a few fields with the same names in the XFA pdf.

Is there a way to rename the duplicate field names with a tool or script?
I tried with LiveCycle Designer, but I don't have all the fonts used in the file, so the end result looked horrible.

Comment: Are you sure that the field names are the same? If I remember correct it is not possible to create such structures in the LiveCycle Designer. At least the path (XFA SOM expression) is unique.

Comment: Yes, the XFA path is unique, but the field name is same. So, it doesn't work with the AcroFields.SetField method of iText used in the software. Tks

Comment: Oh, ok... I didn't know that iText reduces the field name to its last part (is this correct?)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this. And after looking at the iText library and seeing another person's post that he couldn't set field on more than the 1st occurrence of the field name, I decided to find a product that could do it.

I found Evermap's AutoMailMerge plug-in for Acrobat and tried their demo version. It worked well to distinguish between the duplicate field names by fully-qualifying them.

Update 1: Unfortunately, the Evermap plug-in crashed after around 1000 rows/forms. Even after I set the garbage collection setting.

The PDF Mail Merge software was able to handle my test of 4300 rows/forms, it just couldn't deal with the 2nd of the duplicated field names.

Update 2: Good news. I didn't have to figure out how to change the field names. I was able to find that a data structure of the open source software was replacing my fully qualified field names of [] . to () and #s, so I was able to modify the open source software to fix this issue and handle duplicated field names by specifying the fully qualified field names.